# Show a Hidden Div based on the value of a select_box

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a select field in a form, What I am trying to achieve is displaying a form based on the value selected.

Im my case they are forms for types of stripe products.

This is my form:

```
<select name="product[product_type]" id="product_product_type" class="bg-gray-200 text-center">
  <option value="">Select Prod. Type</option>
  <option value="good">Physical Goods</option>
  <option value="service">Electronic Product</option>
</select>

<div class="w-full lg:w-2/3 bg-white p-4 rounded shadow-md types good">
  TEST NEW GOOD Product
</div>
<div class="w-full lg:w-2/3 bg-white p-4 rounded shadow-md types service">
  TEST NEW SERV Product
</div>
```

this is the jQuery I've tried to use to populate..

```
$(function() {
  $('#product_product_type').change(function(){
    $('.types').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

so when I land on the form both divs appear, when I change the value of the select both forms disappear? I've tried to rename, and move things around but to no avail, I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong here?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

`$('.' + $(this).val()).show();`

1. `#` means you are selecting based on id. Here `good` and `service` are actually classes for the two div elements. Therefore you need to use `.` instead
2. If you would like to use `id` selector then you can define `id` attribute on these two divs with these same names `good` and `service`. Then `#` will work too.

Also do check if you are getting the correct value in `$(this).val()` by doing `console.log($(this).val())`

Comment: I dont want to admit that i missed the # over the . but im a bigger person than that.. lol! Thank you so much!